# Sylius works very slow

Tags: performance, symfony, sylius

I installed  Sylius on XAMPP (localhost) and pages load very slowly.

I don't know where I can find configuration to solve my problem.

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is sylius running so slow on local in dev?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470686/why-is-sylius-running-so-slow-on-local-in-dev)

Answer (score 1):

It will be probably just you environment settings, as well as in this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/17474117/1984346

Try using it with `app.dev` instead of `app_dev.php` for a quick check
If it will help, you got you culprit and follow the answers and links bellow.

why is it slow: quote from above answer:

> you are by default installing using the config_dev.yml .... When debug is on ["cache files are dynamically rebuilt on
>   each request."](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html#index-3) This is what is causing the slow speed.

For more information about enviroments: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue for projects base on symfony framework, sylius out from the box don't take care about the performance.

First is follow the https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/performance.html

Next, more complex is using the Varnish proxy cache.

Also, use elastic search for the catalog, product view pages.

Last one is get rid from the coupled frontend part, but use only API side, where fronted build on top of Angular, React or Vue js frameworks.